# mysql error_ unable to insert data into database

Tags: sql-insert

I am trying to insert data in my table, but I am getting:

> "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '@gmail.com, caucasien, Windsor Ontario, Canada,
>   conservative, christian, high sc' at line 1"

Here is my statement:

```
INSERT INTO users (first, last, gender_id, dob, pob, email, ethnicity, city_province, country, nationality, political_view, religious_denomination, level_education)VALUES(pierre,  white, male, 13071970, Canada, pierre.white@gmail.com, caucasien, Windsor Ontario, Canada, conservative, christian, high school);
```

Please help!!!

Comment: You should have quotes around your string values

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes around the string values... `'value'`

```
INSERT INTO users (first, last, gender_id, dob, pob, email, ethnicity, city_province, country, nationality, political_view, religious_denomination, level_education)VALUES('pierre', 'white', 'male', 13071970, 'Canada', 'pierre.white@gmail.com', 'caucasien', 'Windsor Ontario', 'Canada', 'conservative', 'christian', 'high school')
```